# Convert input type text into date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have one input type text:

```
 <input type="text" id="policyholder-dob" name="policyholder-dob" />
```

I want to type number in this field in mm/dd/yyyy format:
like 01/01/2014
This is my js code but its not working, what mistake have I made?

```
function dateFormatter(date) {
    var formattedDate = date.getDate() 
        + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
    return formattedDate;
}

var nextduedate = $("#policyholder-dob").val();

var dateFormatDate = nextduedate.slice(0, 2);
var dateFormatMonth = nextduedate.slice(2, 4);
var dateFormatYear = nextduedate.slice(4, 8);
var totalFormat = dateFormatMonth + '/' + dateFormatDate + '/' + dateFormatYear;
var againNewDate = new Date(totalFormat);
againNewDate.setDate(againNewDate.getDate() + 1);
var todaydate = dateFormatter(againNewDate);

$("#policyholder-dob").prop("value", todaydate);
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js

Comment: no i dont think its meet my requirement if i am tying any digit its giving some date format..

Comment: What's not working? Do you have a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, your input is consistently in this format:

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

So you can convert it to a `Date` object through a custom function, such as:

```
function stringToDate(str){
    var date = str.split("/"),
        m = date[0],
        d = date[1],
        y = date[2],
        temp = [];
    temp.push(y,m,d);
    return (new Date(temp.join("-"))).toUTCString();
}
```

Or:

```
function stringToDate(str){
    var date = str.split("/"),
        m = date[0],
        d = date[1],
        y = date[2];
    return (new Date(y + "-" + m + "-" + d)).toUTCString();
}
```

Etc..

Calling it is easy:

```
stringToDate("12/27/1963");
```

And it will return the correct timestamp in GMT (so that your local timezone won't affect the date (EST -5, causing it to be 26th)):

```
Fri, 27 Dec 1963 00:00:00 GMT //Late december
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/sfqpQ/1/)

There are various ways to accomplish this, this is one of them.

Comment: This is not cross-browser (requires ECMA5 for ISO8601), and is prone to error due to browser differences with string parsing.

Comment: @Xotic750 As I said, there are various ways to do it, this is one of them. What are the browser differences with string parsing though?

Comment: It was just a note to readers. With very little effort you can make this cross-browser and at the same time avoid string parsing pitfalls. There is a great deal of information here on SO about string parsing reliability, I don't intend to repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for date manipulation.  You're going to run into a world of hurt if you're trying to add 1 to month.  What happens when the month is December and you end up with 13 as your month.  Let a library handle all of that headache for you. And you can create your moment date with the string that you pull from the val.  You substrings or parsing.

```
var d = moment('01/31/2014');                 // creates a date of Jan 31st, 2014
var duration = moment.duration({'days' : 1}); // creates a duration object for 1 day
d.add(duration);                              // add duration to date
alert(d.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));                // alerts 02/01/2014
```

[Here's a fiddle showing it off.](http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/YbJdL/)

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately we now (2023) have [`<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) and [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) that removes the need for manual parsing and formatting.

By default this will use the ordering (mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy) and separator (mm/dd/yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy) based on the user's locale

```js
const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat({
  day: '2-digit',
  month: '2-digit',
  year: 'numeric',
});

document
  .getElementById('date')
  .addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    var selectedDate = new Date(e.target.value);
    var formattedDate = formatter.format(selectedDate);
    console.log(formattedDate);
  });
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date"></input>
```

To use a specific locale for the the output, pass it to the DateTimeFormat constructor. e.g. for `dd/mm/yyyy` use `en-US`

```
const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-us', {
  day: '2-digit',
  month: '2-digit',
  year: 'numeric',
});
```